# Antialiasing textures in cycles (Blender 2.77 and higher)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-baking, baking, antialiasing

I would like to get an answer to a frustrating question.

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Cycles

In this link is "Anti-Aliasing is now enabled for baking. (c359343)"

This the great news, and unfortunately in my case it is not working. I try to bake normal maps. I need to bake in full resolution (4k, 8k), and it is not possible to bake 4k and manually changing texture size to e.g 1024 to get in this way manually 4x AA. Currently, I must go to bake in Xnormal (Because I must use cage...Blender internal cannot by used). Xnormal uses AA in bake. The difference in quality is very high.

My question is: It is possible to bake in Cycles normalmaps with AA or if not, whether in the near future it is planned?

Sorry for my very bad english and best regards! Blender is the best! :)

---

Today I checked this again . It seems that Blender bakes almost everything except normal maps with AA . In Ambient Oclussion bake based on the settings in the samples overlap. In the case of the Normal Map settings do not the influence. So please someone versed in the subject matter of the transfer this information of the creators of the blender / notification a bug , etc. There may be a slight correction in the code allows you to add AA ? I see many people need this function.